# Adding icons vertically in list item in normal and hover state not working

Tags: html, css, angular, html-lists

i am working in angular2 html pages. i used li in some ul for making a vertical navigation bar. but i couldn't find i way to show icon and text vertical. is there any way to show text under icons in navigation bar and chage the state of icon when hover. please advise. here is the code for list items. also can i use in line css for showing the icons?

```
<div>

        <ul class="navigationMenu" style="margin-left: 2.3em">
            <li>
                <a class="home" (click)="getNewQuoteFinance()" ><img [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/finance_icon.png']" style="margin:0 0 0px 0; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        Finance<!--<span>Finance</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="about" (click)="getNewQuoteAsset()"><img [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/asset_icon.png']" style="margin:0 0 0px 0; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        Asset <!--<span>Asset</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="services" (click)="getNewQuoteCustomer()"><img [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/customer_icon.png']"
                        style="margin:0 0 0px 0; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        Customer <!--<span>Customer</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="portfolio" style="" (click)="getNewQuoteLpi()"><img [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/lpi_icon.png']" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        LPI  <!--<span>LPI</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="portfolio" (click)="getNewQuoteEpi()"><img
                        [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/epi_icon.png']"
                        style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        EPI  <!--<span>EPI</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="contact" (click)="getNewQuoteMVI()"><img [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/mvi_icon.png']"
                        style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        MVI    <!--<span>MVI</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="contact" (click)="getNewQuoteDiary()"><img [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/diary_icon.png']"
                        style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        Diary   <!--<span>Diary</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>

            <li *ngIf="application.applicationID != null">
                <!--<li >-->
                <a class="contact" (click)="getNewQuoteSaveAsDeal()"><img [src]="['./images/icon/newicons/save-as-deal.png']"
                        style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; width: 40px;height: 40px">
                        SaveAsDeal  <!--<span>Save As Deal</span>-->
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: The same can be done using css, are you using any library like angular material or bootstrap that is making it difficult to achieve vertical icons and text?

Comment: currently using bootstrap and some of my own custom css

Comment: If you create a plunkr of the same, it will be much easier to get the issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add css class for icon and this class you need to add in your "li" tag

```
   #mainmenu .img1{
       background: url('./images/icon/newicons/finance_icon.png') no-repeat top left;
       padding: 2px 0 0 25px;
    }

    #mainmenu .img2{
       background: url('./images/icon/newicons/asset_icon.png') no-repeat top left;
       padding: 2px 0 0 25px;
    }
     And so on...


    <div id="mainmenu">

            <ul class="navigationMenu" style="margin-left: 2.3em">
                <li class="img1">
                    <a class="home" (click)="getNewQuoteFinance()" >
                            Finance<!--<span>Finance</span>-->
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="img2">
                    <a class="about" (click)="getNewQuoteAsset()">
                            Asset <!--<span>Asset</span>-->
                    </a>
                </li>
    And so on ...
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your input, could you please tell me that how to set the hover state and change icon on hover.

Comment: Check this link for change icon state on hover. Hopefully this will solve your problem.  http://callmenick.com/post/nicer-icon-hover-effects-with-css3-transitions